# Should I be flagging "thanks" comments?

Tags: discussion, flagging, comments

I've seen a lot of "thanks" and "me too" comments (even though whenever you add a comment BSE tells you to not leave such comments), especially from the OP.

Should I be flagging these as "not constructive" or "too chatty"? Or are these supposed to just be silently ignored as long as we don't see too many? One could argue that they are serving some purpose by showing that the OP's question has been completely solved, but that's what the accept button is for.

Here is an example:

[How do I create a reflective white material?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62568/how-do-i-create-a-reflective-white-material/62570#comment107653_62570)

Another two examples from today (same question, same comment, OP accepted neither answer):

[Mesh artifacts only on render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62699/mesh-artifacts-only-on-render/62708#comment107901_62708)

[Mesh artifacts only on render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62699/mesh-artifacts-only-on-render/62708#comment107902_62707)

Comment: I think it's good when someone says thanks/+1 *and* makes a comment why they're thankful. Not in the sense of 'thanks you solved my problem' or '+1 for finishing my homework assignment,'  rather, more along the lines of 'thanks [for answering X], I was having trouble also understanding the related Y & Z.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Should +1 and thanks comments be a declined flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279449/278094)
**[Should a "thank you" comment be flagged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169994/278094)**
[Should “Thank you” comments be flagged?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258004/3220986) (really is a separate post)

If you read some of the posts on the meta, you will quickly see two things.

1. Yes you can flag a "Thanks" comments as *Too chatty*.
2. "Thanks" comments are not a big deal.

I personally don't going around deleting many comments.
However when you flag any comment that really says nothing about the post, and is just "thanks" I will definitely delete that.

I make a distinction in "thanks" comment where it goes on to say more. A comment like that (examples below) can really mean something to the poster, and can add value. It is different, and I think should be left.

> Gandalf, when I posted this I didn't realisticly expect to get such a helpful answer so soon and in such a clear way! It solved my issue exactly as intended and I am impressed how fast you solved it, you got good blender logic I guess! Thanks a lot, I will definitely keep coming to this forum for future problems. I would upvote your answer but I need 15 reputation, which I don't have yet :) Anyway, thanks so much and good luck with your own projects!

- [Eegs](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18354/smoke-not-showing-up-in-render/18356#comment26015_18356)

However this comment (I did not delete just for this example) adds nothing and certainly could be deleted.

> thanks that is also very helpful

- [Farhan Anam](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43364/have-i-toggled-wireframe/43365#comment73014_43365)

Another consideration to take in to account is whether or not the comment is blocking more useful content. If there are other comments, especially if there is a *Show more comments* button, then it gets a much higher "Should be deleted" value.

Comment: I just flagged [such a comment](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67532/how-do-i-scroll/67534#comment116814_67534) that provides no instructional information, but the flag was declined.

Comment: @pycoder sorry, that was me earlier. At the time I was thinking I would leave it there until the post author saw it, but I now see that it was you. Again sorry, I'll delete future "thanks" comments.